# How to close an activity from a different activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Activity A running

Activity A starts Activity B

Activity B running

Activity A closed while still in Activity B

Activity A restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `BroadcastReceiver` in *Activity A* and send a broadcast from *Activity B* (or from where ever you want to finish *Activity A*).

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    private FinishReceiver finishReceiver;
    public static final String ACTION_FINISH = 
           "com.mypackage.ActivityA.ACTION_FINISH";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        finishReceiver= new FinishReceiver();
        registerReceiver(finishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(finishReceiver);
    }

    private final class FinishReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FINISH)) 
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Close by calling

```
activityB.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ActivityA.ACTION_FINISH));
```

It's basically the same idea as in [this example](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/how-to-finish-all-activities-in-your-android-application-through-simple-call).

Answer (score 0):

> Activity A closed while still in Activity B

If you mean activity A was paused and stopped, then that always happens when activity B is running.  If you mean activity A was destroyed, that may happen any time it goes into the background, and you have absolutely no control over it.  You should write your activities so the user is completely unaware when they are destroyed in the background.  That's what the "don't keep activities" developer option is for.  Your program should work perfectly with it turned on.  The only consequence of leaving it on all the time should be slightly increased CPU and battery usage from activities constantly reloading their persistent state.